# How to Connect Firebird Database From SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ssms, firebird

I'm new to Firebird databases and trying to connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Would somebody please help me on this, And leave a step by step guide to how to connect a Firebird database using SSMS Version 17.9.1 for example?

For more description:

I want to try connecting to my Firebird database in another location (that means this is remote connection), then run my queries such as select some fields from tables, using my local SSMS.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is to connect to SQL Server, not to Firebird.

Comment: If you want a tool to manage your firebird instance - a subject that is off-topic - go find one. If you want to create a linked server to firebird, just search the internet first and try **the many suggestions**. This may be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I Know i can do google. i did. but looking for better reflection to usage ssms vs firebird. any suggestion?

Comment: You can access Firebird within your SQL Server using SQL Server's Linked Servers. You will need OLEDB driver installed. Once you have SQL Server setup with FIREBIRD via Linked Server, you can run queries against Firebird in SSMS, in terms of performance, it probably would be very efficient. More info can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15